# Touch gestures for Windows 8 multiple desktops

Tags: windows-8, touchpad

Using this lovely (official) SysInternals tool https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881 you can get four (natively supported) desktops from Windows, which you can switch between using a keyboard shortcut.

My question: how can I set things up so that I can use, e.g. a three finger touch swipe to switch between desktops?

Comment: Well, “natively supported” is stretching it quite a bit, isn’t it? ;) You could get some sort of macro program that sends the appropriate keystroke when detecting the touch gesture.

Comment: This tool in question does not support Windows 8.1 not will it ever support it

Comment: Also it doesn't support touch screens that something that would have to be added

Comment: Erm, sorry, the "native support" was referring to the multidesktop support, as opposed to the tool. Yes, a macro program would work, but I don't know how to code it.

Comment: Although, I recently realized that Metro only is active on the FIRST desktop, which is kind of irritating